# C++ add up all bytes in a structure

Tags: c++, struct, osdev

Given a packed struct like this:

```
struct RSDPDescriptor {
    char Signature[8];
    uint8_t Checksum;
    char OEMID[6];
    uint8_t Revision;
    uint32_t RsdtAddress;
} __attribute__ ((packed));
```

How can I sum all of the individual bytes in it?

Comment: All like *all* or all like `Revision + RsdtAddress + Checksum + ...`? Or just the total size or what?

Comment: You would add up the `sizeof` each element. Note that you cannot just ask for `sizeof(RSDPDescriptor)` because that would include padding.

Comment: @Cyber: `__attribute__ ((packed))` has padding?

Comment: @Barry The sum of all the bytes, not the number of bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some code that shows two ways to do it.

The first way is easier and more efficient, but will give the wrong result for a struct that doesn't have the packed attribute (since it will incorrectly include the padding bytes in its tally).

The second approach will work on any struct, padded or packed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

template<typename T> int CountBytes(const T & t)
{
   int count = 0;
   const unsigned char * p = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(&t);
   for (int i=0; i<sizeof(t); i++) count += p[i];
   return count;
}

struct RSDPDescriptor {
    char Signature[8];
    unsigned char Checksum;
    char OEMID[6];
    unsigned char Revision;
    unsigned int RsdtAddress;
} __attribute__ ((packed));

int main(int, char **)
{
   struct RSDPDescriptor x;

   int byteCountFast = CountBytes(x);
   printf("Fast result (only works correctly if the struct is packed) is:  %i\n", byteCountFast);

   int byteCountSafe = CountBytes(x.Signature) + CountBytes(x.Checksum) + CountBytes(x.OEMID) + CountBytes(x.Revision) + CountBytes(x.RsdtAddress);
   printf("Safe result (will work even if there is padding) is:  %i\n", byteCountSafe);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Going to give this a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

I would just forward to [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
template <typename T>
size_t sum_bytes(const T& obj) {
    const unsigned char* p = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&obj);
    return std::accumulate(p, p + sizeof(T), 0u);
}
```

Comment: Kernel programming - can't use std:: stuff.

Comment: @Makerimages Things like what you actually want to do and restrictions you have belong in the question.

Comment: @Makerimages `std::accumulate` is usually a header-only implementation. (aka the code ends up as part of your object file. It doesn't come from a standard precompiled library.) So you sould be fine. (But I would double check your particular compiler first.)